# Can (Kaiju) DNA be scanned from a distance?

Tags: pacific-rim

The [Kaiju drift](http://imdb.com/title/tt1663662/) reveals the breach is secured by DNA fingerprinting.
From what I can tell, the DNA matching doesn't require taking a sample from Kaiju.

I'm only familiar with DNA matching through taking samples:

- blood from finger prick
- cells from cheek swab
- hair follicle
- (and fictional) [blood from ambered mosquito](http://www.theverge.com/2013/9/11/4716484/dinosaur-dna-cannot-be-extracted-from-amber-fossils)

Is there DNA matching research on which this is based? Can (Kaiju) DNA be scanned from a distance?

Comment: Fingerprints are secretions of oil left on objects we touch, and those oils contain our DNA and can be read, it's called [touch DNA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touch_DNA), I haven't seen the movie, could they have meant a literal fingerprint?

Comment: No, the breach is an inter dimensional portal and the Kaiju are building sized monsters. They do not mean a literal fingerprint...

Comment: Related: the drones in Oblivion that presumably scan trace DNA (e.g. the minimal amount you leave everywhere) while flying at 100 MPH, [but can't look in a box...but through rocks?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/12823/how-does-tet-not-recognize-the-body-inside-the-coffin)

Comment: Oblivion sounds interesting, adding it to the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no real life technology that allows for contact-less DNA testing or matching. DNA is not transmitted or otherwise scannable remotely. Of course, we can remotely analysis planets and nebula via radio telescopes, so its not impossible that remote DNA testing could happen.

Additionally, DNA testing requires PCR which currently takes hours to days to replicate enough of the same DNA for analysis. Average time for a DNA comparison is roughly 2~3 days, if you pay well enough for it.

***The remote DNA scanning for access purposes done in the movie is completely fictional. But probable with advance science.***

Comment: This makes the most sense, the only tangentially related science I remembered is amniocentesis, but leads to more questions.